Issues with an element not resizing vertically
I'm making a website layout made to look like the old Windows95 paint window, and I've come across an issue in making the canvas 'window' resizable. It works horizontally, but not vertically. The canvas of the won't expand beyond the min-height I have assigned to it, and I can't figure out how to make it work. Is it because the resize property is attached to the general paint window, and not the inner canvas div? In that case, would I need to attach the resizable class to the canvas, or is there a way around it? I would LOVE to have the inner div expand horizontally as it does vertically. The code I'm using is below.
#paintbox {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
min-width: 628px;
min-height: 446px;
border-right: grey 1px solid;
outline: white 1px solid;
outline-style: outset;
outline-offset: -2px;
border-right: 1px black solid;
border-top: 1px #dedfde solid;
border-left: 1px #dedfde solid;
border-bottom: 1px black solid;
background-color: #bdbebd;
z-index: 9;
top:  10px;
left: 0;
}
.resizable {
overflow: hidden;
resize: both;
min-width: 628px;
min-height: 446px;
}

.canvas {
display: block;
position: absolute;
min-width: 463px;
left: 60px;
min-height: 250px;
outline: black 1px solid;
outline-style: inset;
outline-offset: -2px;
border-left: 1px #7b7b7b solid;
border-bottom: 1px white solid;
border-right: 1px white solid;
border-top: 1px #7b7b7b solid;
background-color: white;
color: black;
margin-right: 3px;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 0 black, inset 2px 0 0 0 black;
}


And I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, unless it's an issue of where I have the resizable property. Here's a codepen link of the entire code.
I've tried resizing and adding different positions to any div I can think of, but nothing seems to give me the solution I want :(
EDIT: Changing the height to a % (i.e. 50%) DOES make the inner canvas change size as it's resized to be whatever % I've specified, but I'm still confused as to why it doesn't change if it's in a pixel specified height. The width changes, so why not the height? I could see if the outer paint window changed while the inner canvas stayed the same, but it doesn't which is where my confusion lies. Am I simply missing something basic?

Can you create a minimal reproducible example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
A large code dump makes things hard for us to debug, and hard for you to identify what is causing the problem. If you can simplify your code to just a simple draggable box with javascript, the problem should become much clearer for us to evaluate.
The old Windows95 browser styling you made is quite beautiful by the way.

@Sam Sabin, thank you for that link! I don't use Slack all that much, and still don't know how to properly format my questions. Also, I ended up figuring the problem out on my own (a parent div was causing problems) but now I've ended up with more problems to solve... If I need to make another question, I'll be sure to try making a reproducible example. And thank you for the compliment!!! I needed that :D

Glad to help and good luck with things!
